# Move an iterator N times C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I seem to be stucked with the following problem:
I want to take the elements from one container and copy them a second container by rearranging its owner in the following way: 
The first container has elements in the order {e_0, e_1 ...e_N-1}
The second container has to have this order {e_0, e_N-1, e_1, e_N-2, ....} 
I am trying to do this with `move_iterator`and pushing as many positions as needed, adding the element to the needed position, and restoring it back with the `base` element, however, I cannot get over the syntax. :( 
Any help will be highly appreciated

```
template<class T>
void front_back_pairing(T& inContainer, T& outContainer)
{
    const int N = inContainer.size();
    int steps = 0;

    for(auto it : inContainer){
        int toBeSkipped = N - steps;
        if(steps % 2 == 0){
            outContainer.push_back(it);
        }else{
            // move iterator to desired position
            auto tempIt = move_iterator<it>(inContainer.begin()+toBeSkipped);
            // push it to the second container 
            outContainer.push_back(tempIt);
            // restore the iterator to its base position 
        }
        steps ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you declare the move_iterator<it>, it is not an iterator, it is actually the value of the object in your container. To have the iterator you might need to have a decltype(inContainer.begin()) in the declaration. As this is clearly not compiling. For more details have a look at https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/move_iterator/

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like that with `move_iterator`:

```
template <class Container>
Container front_back_pairing(Container&& c)
{
    Container res;
    res.reserve(c.size());
    auto it = std::make_move_iterator(c.begin());
    auto rit = std::make_move_iterator(c.rbegin());

    if (c.size() % 2 == 1) {
        while (it.base() != std::prev(rit.base().base())) {
            res.push_back(*it);
            res.push_back(*rit);
            ++it;
            ++rit;
        }
        res.push_back(*it);
    } else {
        while (it.base() != rit.base().base()) {
            res.push_back(*it);
            res.push_back(*rit);
            ++it;
            ++rit;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3eadc86b9bb5117)